# JSON and 2D array

Tags: objective-c, json, multidimensional-array

The following is encoded JSON data from a PHP webpage.

```
{
    {
        "news_date" = "2011-11-09";
        "news_id" = 5;
        "news_imageName" = "newsImage_111110_7633.jpg";
        "news_thread" = "test1";
        "news_title" = "test1 Title";
    },
    {
        "news_date" = "2011-11-10";
        "news_id" = 12;
        "news_imageName" = "newsImage_111110_2060.jpg";
        "news_thread" = "thread2";
        "news_title" = "title2";
    },
// and so on...
}
```

I'd like to grab one buch of info (date/id/image/thread/title), and store it as an instance of a class. However, I have no clue on how to access each object in 2D arrays.
The following is the code I've written to test if I can access them, but it doesn't work.

What would be the problem?

```
NSURL *jsonURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.sangminkim.com/UBCKISS/category/news/jsonNews.php"];
NSString *jsonData = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:jsonURL];
SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
contentArray = [parser objectWithString:jsonData];
NSLog(@"array: %@", [[contentArray objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:0]); // CRASH!!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JSON terminology, that’s not a two-dimensional array: it’s an array whose elements are objects. In Cocoa terminology, it’s an array whose elements are dictionaries.

You can read them like this:

```
NSArray *newsArray = [parser objectWithString:jsonData];

for (NSDictionary *newsItem in newsArray) {
    NSString *newsDate = [newsItem objectForKey:@"news_date"];
    NSUInteger newsId = [[newsItem objectForKey:@"news_id"] integerValue];
    NSString *newsImageName = [newsItem objectForKey:@"news_imageName"];
    NSString *newsThread = [newsItem objectForKey:@"news_thread"];
    NSString *newsTitle = [newsItem objectForKey:@"news_title"];

    // Do something with the data above
}
```

Comment: I totally thought that's 2d array because of what it looks like. Thank you very much!! :)

Answer (score 2):

You gave me a chance to checkout iOS 5 Native JSON parser, so no external libraries needed, try this :

```
-(void)testJson
{
  NSURL *jsonURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.sangminkim.com/UBCKISS/category/news/jsonNews.php"];
  NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:jsonURL];

  NSError* error;
  NSArray* json = [NSJSONSerialization 
                      JSONObjectWithData:jsonData //1

                      options:kNilOptions 
                      error:&error];

  NSLog(@"First Dictionary: %@", [json objectAtIndex:0]);
  //Log output:
  //    First Dictionary: {
  //        "news_date" = "2011-11-09";
  //        "news_id" = 5;
  //        "news_imageName" = "newsImage_111110_7633.jpg";
  //        "news_thread" = " \Uc774\Uc81c \Uc571 \Uac1c\Ubc1c \Uc2dc\Uc791\Ud574\Ub3c4 \Ub420\Uac70 \Uac19\Uc740\Ub370? ";
  //        "news_title" = "\Ub418\Ub294\Uac70 \Uac19\Uc9c0?";
  //    }

  //Each item parsed is an NSDictionary
  NSDictionary* item1 = [json objectAtIndex:0];
  NSLog(@"Item1.news_date= %@", [item1 objectForKey:@"news_date"]);
  //Log output: Item1.news_date= 2011-11-09
}
```